# Appending Changelist to Label in perforce

Tags: perforce

Can you please help me with a command in preface? How do I append a changelist directly to an existing label?

Comment: Could you please show any code you have tried already?

Comment: >p4 labelsync LABEL_NAME -l //...@12345. I tried this..But its not working

Comment: labelsync seem to work only for files not changelists

Comment: Are you trying to change the label so that it refers to a different set of files? Or are you trying to sync your workspace so that it contains (mostly) the files that are referred to by the label, but also contains the files that were modified by a particular changelist? Or, something else entirely?

Comment: Hi Bryan, its the second part. I am trying to append modified files by a particular changelist.

Answer (score 2):

When tagging files with an existing label, specify the changelist number.

For example:

p4 tag -l jam-2.1.0 //depot/release/jam/2.1/src/...@1234

More information and examples of working with labels can be found here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.labels.html

Comment: This changes the contents of the label.  There are opinions surrounding changing the content of a label, most swirling around the purpose of a label, but generally I lean toward "labels should be immutable"  If you need a label at a different point, make a new label - not like labels have any sort of impact on performance or storage overhead, and they provide a more descriptive "history" of code state.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just syncing twice -

```
p4 sync //<mydepotpath>/...@MYLABEL
```

Then -

```
p4 sync //<mydepotpath/...@MYCHANGELIST
```

You can use p4 sync -f if files in the changelist coincide with files in the label, or you *could* just make a new label at the change that includes the MYLABEL files at that change....